# How to allocate image stack in cuda

Tags: cuda

I'm a beginner in the CUDA field.
I want to perform simple naive averaging on x frames (8 bit b&w) for noise reduction (or Median).
How do you recommend allocating the memory for X images?

will this be OK ?

```
    unsigned char** dev_imageStack = new unsigned char*[X];
    for(int i = 0; i < X; i++)
    {
        cudaMalloc( (void**) &dev_imageStack[i], imageSize);
    }
```

Thanks ahead,
Ido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It dependends on the use of dev_imageStack. dev_imageStack is a pointer to CPU memory holding pointers to GPU memory. You would not be able to pass dev_imageStack to a kernel and read from it and your kernel will most likly crash. You could pass dev_imageStack[0].. dev_imageStack[X] to your kernel because that is a pointer to the GPU memory.

If you need to pass all the frames with a pointer i would suggest to allocate a 1D array and perform the frame offset inside the kernel to get the correct frame.

```
unsigned char* dev_imageStack;
cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_imageStack, imageSize*X);
```

And when you use it you should access the frames by offseting into the array with Y*imageSize where Y is the frame you want to access.

If you want to do it similar to the way you described than you have to do it like this:

```
unsigned char** host_imageStack = new unsigned char*[X];

for(int i = 0; i < X; i++)
{
    cudaMalloc( (void**) &host_imageStack[i], imageSize*sizeof(char));
    cudaMemcpy(host_imageStack[i], "char_ptr_to_frame_i_on_host", imageSize*sizeof(char),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}

unsigned char** dev_imageStack;
cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_imageStack, X*sizeof(char*));
cudaMemcpy(dev_imageStack,host_imageStack,X*sizeof(char*),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

And now you could use the dev_imageStack as a 2D pointer to your kernel. Accessing frames and pixels will be done by calling dev_imageStack[frame_id][pixel_id] in kernel.

Comment: On compile time i don't know X so i'll have to use your second advice (cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_imageStack, imageSize*X);                  Any way to do it using two dimenetion array as i would do it in c++?

Comment: but now _dev_imageStack will point to images located on the host, right? I think we should add a for loop allocating data on the device and another loop copying data from host images to device images. 'code' for(int i = 0; i < X) { cudaMemcpy(&dev_imageStack[i], host_imageStack[i], sizeof(char) * imagesize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevicde);

Comment: dev_imateStack is a pointer on GPU pointing on frames in GPU memory. You need to copy your images to GPU memory before using them. This is done by using cudaMemcpy(host_imageStack[i], host_image[i], imageSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)

Comment: Just to clarify. host_imageStack is a pointer on CPU but host_imageStack[i] is an address to GPU memory.

Answer (score 0):

In an own project I solved this by this way:

```
unsigned char* dev_imageStack;
cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_imageStack, imageSize * frames );

unsigned char* dev_image1 = dev_imageStack;
unsigned char* dev_image2 = dev_image1 + imageSize;
...
unsigned char* dev_imageN = dev_imageN-1 + imageSize;
```

I've allocated just one big memoryblock and use pointers to several "subblocks".

If you want an array containing this pointers to the "subblocks" you can do this like this way.

```
void* dev_images;
cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_images_tmp, frames * sizeof( unsigned char* ) );
unsigned char** dev_images = (unsigned char**)dev_images_tmp;
```

Now in a kernel you can call the image of frame x in this way:

```
dev_images[x][index];
```

With index you can grab the elements of the destinatet image.

Comment: Ah, ok. I used some compareable in an own project, I will update my answer how I solved this for me.